# Array is being overwritten via array_push()

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to push elements to an array for later averaging but every one that is pushed with `array_push()` will just overwrite so the expected array output of 10 elements is coming to just one with the last pushed value.

```
array:2 [▼
  "raw" => array:10 [▼
    "averagePar3GrossScore" => array:1 [▼
      0 => 5.67
    ]
    "averagePar4GrossScore" => array:1 [▶]
    "averagePar5GrossScore" => array:1 [▶]
    "averagePuttTotal" => array:1 [▶]
    "sumEagles" => array:1 [▶]
    "sumBirdies" => array:1 [▶]
    "sumPars" => array:1 [▶]
    "sumBogeys" => array:1 [▶]
    "sumDoubleBogeys" => array:1 [▶]
    "sumOverDoubleBogeys" => array:1 [▶]
  ]
  "averaged" => []
]
```

```
// Temp data
$currentAverages = 0;
$averages = [
    "raw" => [
        "averagePar3GrossScore" => [],
        "averagePar4GrossScore" => [],
        "averagePar5GrossScore" => [],
        "averagePuttTotal" => [],
        "sumEagles" => [], // Use sum for average type
        "sumBirdies" => [], // Use sum for average type
        "sumPars" => [], // Use sum for average type
        "sumBogeys" => [], // Use sum for average type
        "sumDoubleBogeys" => [], // Use sum for average type
        "sumOverDoubleBogeys" => [] // Use sum for average type
    ],
    "averaged" => []
];

// Get initial stats
$stats = json_decode($this->stats($from, $to, $createdAfter, $createdBefore)->getBody());
$currentAverages = $stats->resultsCount;

foreach ($averages["raw"] as $statName => $statValue) {
    $testArr = [];
    foreach ($stats->roundExtendedStats as $roundKey => $round); {
        array_push($averages["raw"][$statName], $round->$statName);
        // $newStat = $round->$statName;
        // echo $newStat;
        //array_push($averages["raw"][$statName], $newStat);
    }
}

dd($averages);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foreach ($stats->roundExtendedStats as $roundKey => $round);`

The semicolon at the end of this was causing the loop to execute but the code block was not getting run.

Removing that semicolon solved the issue and worked as expected.